# How to make a "live" function without ajax requests on intervals

Tags: ajax

I want to make a website, where the user gets a live notification if a file on the server gets  edited (for example).

I could do this with an ajax call and if/else statement to check if there is anything new, but was wondering if it is possible to do it another way, without having to resort to infinite HTTP requests.

Is there another possibility to do this? If yes how would it work?

Comment: Your specification is a bit vague, but depending on your server-side technology, you could use something like [Websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).. if you are using .Net look into SignalIR or ASPComet.. otherwise, you could look into something like node.js

Comment: i thought i might have to resort to node.js... isnt there a php solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: http://socket.io/

Even though it uses Node.JS on the server side which could be a problem.